# vue enter transition not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, animation, vue.js, vuejs2

i'm working on a project where i have to render some components with an enter and leave animation, when a component enters the screen it has to enter form the bottom, and when it leaves, it has to do it going upwards, the desired behavior is that when i change the :is property of the component tag, the current component goes upwards and the next one comes from the bottom, the code looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <transition name="section">
      <component :is="activeSection"></component>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import comp1 from './comp1';
import comp2 from './comp2';

export default {
  components: {
    comp1,
    comp2
  },
  data() {
    activeSection: 'comp1'
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  .section-enter {
    top: 100vh;
  }
  .section-enter-to {
    top: 0vh;
  }
  .section-enter-active {
    animation-name: 'slideIn';
    animation-duration: 1s;
  }
  .section-leave {
    top: 0vh;
  }
  .section-leave-active {
    animation-name: 'slideOut';
    animation-duration: 1s;
  }
  .section-leave-to {
    top: -100vh;
  }


  @keyframes slideIn {
    from {
      top: 100vh;
    }
    to {
      top: 0
    }
  }

  @keyframes slideOut {
    from {
      top: 0vh;
    }
    to {
      top: -100vh;
    }
  }
</style>
```

but the actual behavior is that the first component goes upwards but the second appears inmediatly after without animation.

if i render one at a time (not destructing one and rendering another with the same action) everything works perfectly. I dont know what is happening.

Comment: could you please put this somewhere like codesandbox so its easier to recreate and look into?

Comment: Hey, in my case, I just had to add an `appear` attribute to my transition. Hope it may help the others having this issue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few problems in your CSS.

#### CSS Transitions and CSS Animations

A transition can be implemented using *either* [CSS Transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#CSS-Transitions) *or* [CSS Animations](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#CSS-Animations). Your CSS incorrectly mixes the two concepts in this case.

In particular, the `slideIn` keyframes and `.section-enter`/`.section-enter-to` rules are effectively performing the same task of moving `.section` into view. However, this is missing a [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) rule with a non-zero time, required to animate the change, so the change occurs immediately. The same issue exists for the `slideOut` keyframes and `leave` rules.

```
.section-enter {
  top: 100vh;
}
.section-enter-to {
  top: 0;
}
.section-enter-active {
  transition: .5s; /* MISSING RULE */
}

.section-leave {
  top: 0;
}
.section-leave-to {
  top: -100vh;
}
.section-leave-active {
  transition: .5s; /* MISSING RULE */
}
```

Removing the keyframes, and adding the missing rules (as shown above) would result in a working CSS Transition.

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/xvnvwqzqxw?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHome.vue)

#### Using CSS Animations

Alternatively, you could use keyframes with CSS Animations, where the animation is applied only by the `*-active` rules, and no `*-enter`/`*-leave` rules are used. *Note your question contained unnecessary quotes in `animation-name: 'slideIn';`, which is invalid syntax and would be silently ignored (no animation occurs). I use a simpler shorthand in the following snippet (`animation: slideIn 1s;`).*

```
.section-enter-active {
  animation: slideIn 1s;
}
.section-leave-active {
  animation: slideOut 1s;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    top: 100vh;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes slideOut {
  from {
    top: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: -100vh;
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/01qm75l1nw?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHome.vue)

#### Optimizing CSS Transitions

You could also [tweak your animation performance](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) by using [`translateY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateY) instead of transitioning `top`.

```
/* top initially 0 in .wrapper */

.section-leave-active,
.section-enter-active {
  transition: .5s;
}
.section-enter {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
.section-leave-to {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

[demo 3](https://codesandbox.io/s/4ry74q8kqw?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHome.vue)

Answer (score -1):

## Use a Mixin

Thanks for the explanation [@tony19](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54279839/11155364)
please use a mixin for this so the logic can be repeated easily.
Also, your slideIn and slideOut can be combined by using reverse:

```
@mixin animationmixin($type:'animation', $style:'', $duration:1s) {
    
    @keyframes #{$type}-#{$style} { // register animation
        0% { opacity: 1;  transform: none; } // reset style
        100% { @content; } // custom style
    }
    
    .#{$style} { // add '.section'
        &-enter-active, &-leave-active { // add '.section-enter-active', ...
            transition: #{$duration};
        }
        &-enter, &-leave-to {
            animation: #{$type}-#{$style} #{$duration}; // use animation
        }
        &-leave, &-enter-to {
            animation: #{$type}-#{$style} #{$duration} reverse; // use animation in reverse 
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
@include animationmixin($style:'section') { // set custom styling
    transform: translateY(100%);
};
```

And like this:

```
@include animationmixin($style:'fade') {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.9);
};
```